# Signature-pad no funciona en ventanas modal

Tags: javascript, html, signature

Tengo dos ventanas modales una se abre después de cerrar la otra y estoy intentando agregar la librería de [Signature-pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) que se utiliza para firmas electrónicas, estoy intentando agregar a cada ventana modal un pad para la firma pero solo se pinta el recuadro y cuando intento firmar no se ve trazo de la firma. El siguiente es un pequeño fragmento que he preparado para explicar lo que estoy intentando realizar:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  $('#basicModal').modal({ show: false});
  $('#basicModal').modal('show');
});

function save() {
  $('#basicModal').modal('toggle');
  $('#anotherModal').modal('show');
}

var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);

var signaturePad1 = new SignaturePad(canvas1);
```

```css
.signature-pad {
    position: relative; 
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   -webkit-box-direction: normal;
       -ms-flex-direction: column;
           flex-direction: column;
   font-size: 10px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 30%;
   max-width: 600px;
   max-height: 460px;
   border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
   background-color: #fff;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08) inset;
   border-radius: 4px;
   padding: 16px;
 }

 .signature-pad1 {
    position: relative; 
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   -webkit-box-direction: normal;
       -ms-flex-direction: column;
           flex-direction: column;
   font-size: 10px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 30%;
   max-width: 700px;
   max-height: 460px;
   border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
   background-color: #fff;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08) inset;
   border-radius: 4px;
   padding: 16px;
 }
 
  .signature-pad1::before,
.signature-pad1::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  width: 40%;
  height: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
 
  .signature-pad--body {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  }

  .signature-pad--body1 {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/signature_pad/1.5.3/signature_pad.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad">
                    <div class="signature-pad--body">
                        <canvas id="canvas" width="565" height="100"></canvas>
                    </div>
                    <div class="signature-pad--footer">
                        <div class="signature-pad--actions" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                            <div>
                                <button type="button" class="button clear" data-action="clear">Limpiar</button>
                            </div>                              
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="anotherModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="anotherModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Another Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="signature-pad1" class="signature-pad1">
                    <div class="signature-pad--body1">
                        <canvas id="canvas1" width="565" height="100"></canvas>
                    </div>
                    <div class="signature-pad--footer">
                        <div class="signature-pad--actions" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                            <div>
                                <button type="button" class="button clear" data-action="clear">Limpiar</button>
                            </div>                              
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

No se si tenga mal declarada alguna de las clases, o me haga falta utilizar alguna librería adicional, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar con este problema.

Comment: Estás duplicando ID y estos [deben ser únicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/id).

Comment: @Triby Acabo de validar los ID y ya no los estoy duplicando pero aun así sigue sin funcionar, alguna otra sugerencia ?

Comment: Sí, lee nuevamente la [forma de uso](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad#api), parece que te falta inicializar los elementos.

Comment: Excelente sugerencia, me faltaba incializar los elementos `var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");` `var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);` 
`var signaturePad1 = new SignaturePad(canvas1);`